# Temporarily disable Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to disable an Eclipse plugin without actually uninstalling it?

(Eclipse 3.3 had a "disable" button but this is now missing from Eclipse 3.4+.)

Comment: You might like to clarify that you are asking about Eclipse 3.4+; Eclipse 3.3 had a "disable" command for each feature.

Comment: Eclipse 3.3 is 2 years old so I didn't assume people would even consider it. But I'll edit the question...

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Some plugins allow controlling their load-on-startup behavior. These will be listed in the preferences, under General → Startup and Shutdown. If the plugin provides view, you will need to close those views (in all perspectives) for this to work.

[image: Startup and Shutdown]

Comment: Image link is broken.

Answer (score 22):

First enable classic update in preference under :

**General > Capabilities**, then go to 
**Help > Software Updates > Manage Configuration** to disable it.

Below two links for your information

[This](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-32.htm) and [this](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-35.htm) link can help you.

Comment: the links be broke.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [bug 224145#c34](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=224145#c34),

> I don't see any way to enable stuff except for what is in the p2 UI. And I see no update stuff there at all - not even in the list of things to install.
>
> p2 don't even seem to have enable/disable functionality, only install/uninstall.

In other world, in the [P2 universe (since Eclipse 3.4)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Category:Equinox_p2), there doesn't seem to be a "disable" process, and the word was not used in the [Ganymede Plan](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Ganymede/Plan) or [Galileo Plan](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Galileo/Plan).