# Eclipse Hang When Cancel Background Process

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: Eclipse Hang]

1. I want to cancel background operation currently running on Eclipse.
2. Because it's taking a long time, I restart eclipse
3. But I've been waiting for 30Mins++ and see the images above until I post this here.
4. Anyone here know why this happens and how to fix this ? (I want to fix this problem without killing background process at Windows Task Manager)

FYI:
I'm running Eclipse Helios on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit with 4GB RAM

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your SVN plugin or other plugins? Try disabling some or all your plugins to help you diagnose if this is a plugin issue. Refer to this question on how to disable plugins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978174/temporarily-disable-eclipse-plugin also if this is a large project try giving eclipse more ram by adding the -Mmx=xxx option in eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling build automatically from project menu. The problem is if you kill eclipse it will not save this setting so you need to be fast to disable this setting again once you started.

Comment: Lol "you need to be fast to disable this setting again once you started", seriously, can you not give the relevant property to change in a config file ??