# Why Eclipse is too slow on startup?

Tags: eclipse, startup

I am using windows 7 home premium with service pack 1 installed. I had installed JDK 1.7u21. Then I downloaded Eclipse Juno (Before that I was using Eclipse Indigo with JDK 1.6u26) and when I started it, I found out that it is taking too much time to start. It is pausing on the splash screen for more than 10 minutes, and then only asks for the workspace selection.

Then I removed Juno and installed Indigo again, also uninstalled JDK 1.7 and installed JDK 1.6u45, but now also the problem persists. When I searched, I have found that deleting files in the `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources` will fix he problem. I have done that also, but no use.

The below given is my 'eclipse.ini'

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Did you work on the number of projects that was open when the eclipse is closed?

Comment: i dont think anybody can help u with that by seeing that file..

Comment: @oneliner, I have an empty workspace now.

Comment: @Nitin, I know that. I was wondering whether heap size or some other configuration settings has anything to do with it or may be somebody has similar problem and solved it.

Comment: It may be depend on many things kauhshik. May be you machines performance, may me available memory / CPU in your machine etc.

Comment: hmm..i use juno and jdk7 and i hv no problem.. try opening eclipse with a new workspace..this way u will find if your problem is with your workspace or not..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Basically, there might be too many plugins at startup which might be creating this mess. You must disable these startup plugins

Take a look at the previous post [Temporarily disable Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978174/temporarily-disable-eclipse-plugin)

Another very good guide to speed up eclipse is given as under. 
http://www.beyondlinux.com/2011/06/25/speed-up-your-eclipse-as-a-super-fast-ide/

A previous StackOverflow post also talks of speeding up eclipse 
[How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse)

You can also see the list of plugins that are loaded at startup at [image]

Comment: I want to disable CVS plugin, as CVS is dead and it is no longer used in most projects.

Comment: I have updated the answer with another previous post on speeding up eclipse and here is the link about uninstalling cvs from eclipse http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/09/removing-cvs-from-eclipse-platform.html

Comment: @AuraA, I have removed all plugins except 'MyLyn' from startup and removed all validation except Class Path validator. Now I am again a happy eclipse user, but I still wonder how my previous installation of eclipse(Indigo + jdk 1.6u26) worked well without these tweaks ?

Comment: @AurA, I have tried tricks from this site also: http://blog.sarathonline.com/2012/05/eclipse-indigo-without-mylyn.html.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much to go on, so I'll give a few things to try to collect additional information:

- Use JVisualVm to monitor the process and look at the threads.  You can find this in the JDK bin folder.  Once started, the Eclipse should appear in the left pane under 'Local',  Double-click it to open then go the the threads tab and try to correlate it's behavior (running/hanging/sleeping) with particular thread activity.  You might also try a 'thread dump' and see what objects threads are hanging on.
- Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to trace all file, registry, and network activity during Eclipse start up try to correlate this with the behavior you see.  You might also try disabling your network device(s) to see if this affects it--perhaps it is hanging while trying to contact maven or update sites.
- Check the Eclipse log file in `.metatdata/.log` in your workspace directory for (error) messages.  This is the easiest thing to do, so look here first.

These are all general "information gathering" steps which may help you to ask more specific questions.  Googling "[why does eclipse hang during startup minutes](https://www.google.com/search?q=why%20does%20eclipse%20hang%20during%20startup%20minutes)" shows this is not uncommon, and there are few different causes/solutions.