# Install Eclipse without any Features

Tags: eclipse

The standard/class edition of eclipse still includes JDT, CVS, GIT and various other features.

Is there a way to install it with only 'resource' management/project tools.
Essentially a version of eclipse built without any language or environment in mind.

A lot like an operating system without any programs installed other than what it needs to run itself and provide the means to install programs entirely at the user's discretion.

Post Answer:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3-201306052000/
The eclipse-platform section contains no-frills, just raw eclipse.

Comment: Look this link if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978174/temporarily-disable-eclipse-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this link (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/custom.php) It should contain what is called a Eclipse Platform Runtime Binaries which is the most minimalist package available.

Comment: It seems to be Eclipse 3.3 . Not the latest version of eclipse.

Comment: I'm looking into it.  There are other builds of 4.3 that aren't labeled as kepler.

Comment: Almost there, the cpp package doesn't include any of the jdt plugins.  I was worried that eclipse had a hard dependency on it.  Im looking for the build used before it is merged with other features.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer I wrote in: [Eclipse without plugins for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034373/eclipse-without-plugins-for-windows/42374868)

You can download it from here: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html. There you can find 'clean' builds of Eclipse, which do not ship with common development tools.

Answer (score 0):

You still can uninstall the plugins you don't want this way :

```
Menu > Help > About eclipse SDK > Installation details
Install software tab
Select the plugin you don't want
Uninstall button
```

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't seem to let you remove any plugins that were shipped with the package.  org.eclipse.team.csv.* for example, I don't need that, but it won't allow me to remove it.  I could remove them manually but I don't know enough about eclipse to remove them safely.

Comment: Go to the "Installed software" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Goto https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Choose a release

e.g. "Latest Release : 4.10" --> https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.10-201812060815/

On this new page choose "**Platform Runtime Binary**"

It contains the Eclipse Rich Client Platform base bundles and do not contain source or programmer documentation.