# Eclipse without plugins for windows

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse 3.8.1 right now on Xubuntu and there were no problems until now. But 2 days ago some friends and me started a project together, they are using Windows 7 and Windows 8 (x64). When I installed eclipse in Xubuntu, it didnt have any plugins and features installed but I couldnt find any eclipse version for windows that has no plugins pre-installed.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks a lot for every idea! :)

Comment: Eclipse is all plugins! Eclipse Standard 4.3.2 is fine if you just want Java development.

Comment: A freshly installed eclpse has no plugins. Just like the one you had on Xubuntu.

Comment: But the directories plugins and features already had a lot of .jar files, that was not the case in xubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm three years late but: you can download it from here: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html. There you can find 'clean' builds of Eclipse, which do not ship with common development tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you do an `apt-get install eclipse`, it gets installed in a read-only directory; each user that runs Eclipse gets their own directory with the plugins he/she installs afterwards from within Eclipse.

On both Windows and Linux, you can just download a zip file of Eclipse, unzip it somewhere, and then run it directly. This is also the way to run different versions of Eclipse, and there is just one place for each version to store plugins: within its own directory.