# How to temporarily stop Crashlytics from auto-generating its files

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, crashlytics

I am attempting to merge several branches within my SVN project in Eclipse Juno, with Crashlytics 1.1.0 integrated. However, Eclipse is telling me I need a clean workspace to do so. Crashlytics likes to constantly regenerate the `com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml` file, which is preventing me from maintaining my clean workspace.

**How can I temporarily disable Crashlytics so I can merge my branches and then reenable the plugin?**

- I've already read this which did not help: [Temporarily disable Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978174/temporarily-disable-eclipse-plugin)
- I've removed the `Crashlytics.start()` call in my main activity
- I've tried "logging out" of the plugin as referenced [here](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/214659-how-to-logout-of-the-crashlytics-plugin)
- I've also tried turning off "Build Automatically" from the Project menu

But even with all these steps the plugin still regenerates the file immediately. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue when merging branches with Crashlytics implemented.

I found out that the I accidentally commited the com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml (res/values/) to my svn repository.

My quick fix was to delete the com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml file from the svn repository (as I did not incorporate the file into svn:ignore right now).

How I did it:

1. Delete the com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml from your trunk project in eclipse.
2. Commit the change (deleted com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml file) to the repository.

Now, you should be able to merge your feature branch into your trunk without any issues, as your svn repository won't have a different com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml file to conflict with.